# Quarkus SSE Redis subscribe

Tags: java, redis, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events, quarkus

I like to do an SSE with the response of redis.subscribe in quarkus.

I have a sample from the quarkus-quickstart for a simple SSE

```
 @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
  @SseElementType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Path("{name}/streaming")
  public Multi<String> greeting(@org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.jaxrs.PathParam String name) {
    return Multi.createFrom().publisher(vertx.periodicStream(2000).toMulti())
        .map(l -> String.format("Hello %s! (%s)%n", name, new Date()));
  }
```

This work well, every 2 seconds I received the Hello .... in my web browser

Now I try to subscribe to Redis, so I should receive the message from Redis.

Redis sample :

```
(cmd window 1)
SUBSCRIBE message-channel
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "message-channel"
3) (integer) 1

(cmd window 2)
PUBLISH  message-channel HelloWorld
(integer) 1

(cmd window 1)
1) "message"
2) "message-channel"
3) "HelloWorld"
```

Now I try this with quarkus SSE:

```
  @Inject
  ReactiveRedisClient reactiveRedisClient;

 @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
  @SseElementType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Path("sse/redissse")
  public Multi<String> redissse() {
    List<String> subscriberList = new ArrayList();
    subscriberList.add("message-channel");

    return reactiveRedisClient.subscribe(subscriberList)
        .onItem().transformToMulti(keys -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(keys))
        .onItem().castTo(String.class);
  }
```

what I received was an exception:

```
WARNING [io.ver.red.cli.imp.RedisConnectionImpl] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) No handler waiting for message: [subscribe, message-channel, 1]
```

Could anyone support me?
Is there a simple example?
I have no clue about it, I can't receive Redis messages with "subscribe" publish.

any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Redis pub-sub, but I did use Redis streams and what I had to do was something like this:

`

```
return Multi.createBy().repeating()
    .supplier(() -> this.reactiveRedisClient.subscribe(subscriberList)
                        .onItem().transformToMulti(keys -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(keys))
                        .onItem().castTo(String.class))
        .indefinitely()
        .onItem().disjoint();
```

`

I guess since pub-sub is non-blocking, it runs once then it doesn't wait till another message arrives. You have to implement your own `while(true)` loop in a reactive way.

Answer (score 0):

Now I do the following:

```
  @Inject
  @RedisClientName("second")
  RedisClient redisClient2;

void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) throws IOException {
  this.redisClient2.subscribe(List.of("message-channel"));
}


  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
  @SseElementType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Path("/redis/subscribe")
  public Publisher<String> subscribechannel(){
     return eventBus.<String>consumer("io.vertx.redis.message-channel").toPublisherBuilder()
        .map(Message::body)
        .buildRs();
  }
```

Now it works, but If I do SSE from more than browsers they share the events. So only one of each received an event after each other consumer (browser).